# Is there a way to create an arrow function from a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, string, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

A JSON response like this:

```
res = {
  onChange: "() => { console.log() }",
  .....
}
```

How to make the string in res.onChange be an arrow function.

`res.onChange = Function("() = { console.log()}");` Do not solve my problem.

Comment: That string in your example is missing the `>` symbol: `res.onChange = Function("() = { console.log()}");`

Comment: `eval` is a step toward a solution to your problem. Don't expect to be spoonfed exact code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval` to execute a string as code.

`eval("() => { console.log('no') }")();`

Or if you need some string interpolation:

```
const foo = 'bar';
eval(`() => { console.log('${foo}') }`)();
```

Be careful of malicious injection.

Edit: OP, you should be able to extrapolate what you need to do from here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()`:

```
res.onChange = new Function(res.onChange.replace(/\\(\\)\s=>\s\\{|\\}$/,""))
```